# From TcxCheckListBox to TcxCheckGroupBox (Load States from TStringStream)

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Anyone can help how can I transfrom this to work with `TcxCheckGroup`? My procedure can be load checked `Items` states to `cxCheckListBox`.

Working example with `TcxCheckListBox`...

```
procedure Tfrm.LoadStatesFromStream(SS: TStringStream);
var
  i : integer;
  S2 : String;
begin

  SS.Position := 0;
  i := 0;
while (i <= cxCheckListBox1.Items.Count - 1) and (SS.Position < SS.Size) do    
begin
  S2 := SS.ReadString(1);
  cxCheckListBox1.Items[i].Checked := S2 = '+';
  Inc(i);
end;
end;
```

I need a help with...

```
procedure Tfrm.LoadStatesFromStream(SS: TStringStream);
var
  i : integer;
  S2 : String;
begin
  SS.Position := 0;
  i := 0;
while (i <= cxCheckGroup1.Properties.Items.Count - 1) and (SS.Position <   SS.Size) do
begin
  S2 := SS.ReadString(1);
  (cxCheckGroup1.States[i] = cbschecked ):= S2 = '+';  //I have a problem here

  Inc(i);
 end;
end;
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are tackling this the wrong way. You should be using a structured format like JSON instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I am very new in delphi, I am just learning it. Thank you for your advice , I will be sure to look after the JSON format, but I need this formát right now. Thanks!

Comment: No you don't. You are just storing up lots of trouble in the future.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Actually, I think the problem for a beginner with the Devex library is just finding your way around the innards of  the components.  F.i, the OP's TcxCheckBoxGroup's sub-members are exposed and accessed in a different way than the TcxCheckList, which on the face of it is just another way of containerising the Devex checkboxes.  In any case, if the OP wasn't a novice, he could just use native streaming routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the code below;  I assumed that you want to include the possibility that a checkbox's state might be `cbsGrayed` (which I've represented by a space character in the StringStream.

```
function CheckBoxStateToString(CheckBoxState : TcxCheckBoxState ) : String;
begin
  Result := '';
  case CheckBoxState of
    cbsChecked : Result := '+';
    cbsUnChecked : Result := '-';
    cbsGrayed : Result := ' ';
  end;
end;

function StringToCheckBoxState(Input : String) : TcxCheckBoxState;
begin
  Result := cbsGrayed;
  if Input = '+' then
    Result := cbsChecked
  else
    if Input = '-' then
      Result := cbsUnChecked
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveCheckGroupStatesToStream(SS : TStringStream);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  SS.Clear;
  SS.Position := 0;
  for i := 0 to cxCheckGroup1.Properties.Items.Count - 1 do begin
      SS.WriteString(CheckBoxStateToString(cxCheckGroup1.States[i]));
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('>' + SS.DataString + '<');
end;

procedure TForm1.LoadCheckGroupStatesFromStream(SS : TStringStream);
var
  i : integer;
  S : String;
begin
  CheckBoxList.ClearCheckmarks;
  SS.Position := 0;
  i := 0;
  while (i <= cxCheckGroup1.Properties.Items.Count - 1) and (SS.Position < SS.Size) do begin
    S := SS.ReadString(1);
    cxCheckGroup1.States[i] := StringToCheckBoxState(S);
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;
```